# If I have an instance of JWPlayerController how can I find out the file that is currently playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, jwplayer

```
JWConfig * config = [JWConfig new];
config.file = @"https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8";
self.player = [[JWPlayerController alloc] initWithConfig:config];
[self.player play];
```

Later on, with the same player instance I can do something like this:

```
JWPlaylistItem * item = [JWPlaylistItem new];
item.file = @"http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8";
[self.player load:@[ item ]];
[self.player play];
```

If I have a reference to `self.player` how can I get the URL of the file that is currently playing?

I have tried:

```
self.player.config.file
```

This doesn't work, because it will return the original file from the initialization (bitdash-a.akamaihd.net...)

From the `player` instance I can't find a way to get a reference to the currently playing `playlistItem`

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with jw player on iOS. https://github.com/jwplayer/JWPlayer-iOS-SDK-cocoapod/issues/49

The SDK intends to add a `getPlaylistItem` method for this purpose